# Carousel not rotating after changing to dynamic script

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I have changed my static code for an carousel to an dynamic code. For some reason the carousel is not rotating the images. I have put the website online for viewing: [here](https://torza.nl/test_environment/vert/)

```
  <?php
  $files = glob('img/carousel/*.*');
  shuffle($files);    
  $no_files = count($files);
  ?>

<header>
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <?php
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $no_files; $x++)
        {
            echo '<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="'.$x.'" '; if($x == 0) { echo 'class="active"'; } echo'></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

      <?php
      foreach($files as $file)
      {
          echo '<div class="carousel-item active" style="background-image: url('.$file.')">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                </div>
              </div>';
      }
      ?>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Vorige</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Volgende</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: One problem is that in your second PHP loop, you mark all items with class "active". You should apply the same logic as you did in the first loop, making sure you only apply that class to one element, not all.

Comment: Thx trincot... That was the only issue I had :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thanks to trincot changed the second loop to:

```
  <?php
  $y = 0;
  foreach($files as $file)
  {
      $y++;
      echo '<div class="carousel-item'; if($y == 1) { echo ' active'; } echo'" style="background-image: url('.$file.')">
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
            </div>
          </div>';
  }
  ?>
```